# How come I can't install Google Maps in Israel?

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps doesn't seem to be available in the market when I'm in Israel. When I travel to Europe it appears. How come?
(I'm on CyanogenMod 7, but that shouldn't matter right?)

I have more or less [the same problem on my iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76874/how-come-google-maps-isnt-available-in-location-specific-app-stores)!

**UPDATE:**
What I meant was that when in Europe I can *install* Google Maps and then it works great in Israel. Google Maps covers Israel weather you're there or not, the only hurdle is that within Israel you can't install it.

Answer (score 1):

Google probably disables Google Maps in Israel largely for security reasons.

Google Street View in Israel was enabled only some time in [2012](http://www.seroundtable.com/israel-google-street-views-15039.html). Older news reports say that Google Maps for Israel was [totally blank](http://www.seraphicpress.com/google-maps-go-dark-on-israel/) from some areas (especially areas that may attack Israel).

BTW, I can see Israel in Google Maps from my place (Philippines).

Related information:
[Why Google Earth Pixelates Israel](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2386907,00.asp)

Comment: See my Update in the question

Comment: @Jonathan Maybe Google Maps is not allowed / supported in Israel (and Google can detect that based on your IP address). In my case, although the Philippines has access to Google Maps app, Google Earth app is not supported for our country. BUT, I can still install Google Earth on my PC though.